# AVPlayer asset duration is smaller then currentTime

Tags: swift

Hi I have a strange issue with AVPlayer

I have added

> addPeriodicTimeObserver

and sometimes after seeking video/audio players duration becomes smaller then currentTime value

I am seeking player wtih this line

```
seek(to: avPlayer.currentTime() + CMTimeMake(20,1 ), toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
```

can this be an issue?